# Why table field keeps the old value while update?

Tags: laravel, insert-update

When I press the update button of my application, it keeping the old value and does't apply return redirect functionality.

Create, Edit and delete is working properly
I tried composer update and cache clear but the situation is not changed,
thanks for help

```
   class CategoryController extends Controller
{




    public function store(CategoryRequest $request)
    {
        //

        Category::create($request->all());
        session()->flash('success','Data added successfully');
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.categories.index');

    }


    public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
       // return $request;
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required'
       ]);

            // $category= Category::find($id);
        $category->update($request->all());
        $category->save();
        session()->flash('success','data updated successfully');
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.categories.index');
    }


}
```

**My Route**

```
    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');

});
```

thanks a lot

Comment: did you try $category->update($request->toArray()) ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it now, did not work

Comment: did you already put Mass Assignment in your category model ?

Comment: you must fields in Category model in  (( protected $fillable = ['fields1' , ... ] ))

Comment: yes, 
{
    //
    protected $fillable=['name'];
}

Comment: is name only you want to update ? or maybe there are some data included in your request

Comment: all fields that need update added in $fillable  varible

Comment: yes ,         protected $fillable=['name'];

Comment: category table has only one field 'name'

Comment: use  $category->name = $request->name ; 
instead of  $category->update($request->all());

Comment: remove also the save method after update

Comment: and are you sure you access correctly your update function ?

Comment: $category->name = $request->name and removed save() , unfortunately did not work

Comment: don't remove  save() method !!!!

Comment: this is my edit.blade                 <form  method="POST" action="{{route('dashboard.categories.update', $category->id)}}">
            @method('PUT')
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="Name" value="{{old('name', $category->name)}}" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Update</button>
            </div>

        </form>

Comment: bugggg  name="Name" with lowercase  name="name"

Comment: my code now is :                  public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
       // return $request;
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required'
       ]);

            // $category= Category::find($id);
        // $category->update($request->all());
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->save();
        session()->flash('success','data updated successfully');
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.categories.index');
    }

Comment: code is run truly?

Comment: $category->name = $request->name ;
 $category->save();   
 dont forget save method

Comment: still update does not work

Comment: are you sure you access correctly your update function by putting echo on it ?

Comment: it returns updated value when I commented all code except return $request      {
_method: "PUT",
_token: "k4uw8JDGJm9JKxMJ5kacijcLNmyE1newar1kNGPm",
Name: "category UPDATED"   
}

Comment: It works now when I changed into Name not name like this:               $category->name = $request->Name;
=====   Although field name is small n not capital======

Comment: Thanks to all of you , I spent 3 days trying to solve it, I did it by your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$category->name = $request->Name; //not name//

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had mass assignment fields in your model.

so to be sure your in correct path. If it still does not work. Check code below.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
       // return $request;
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required'
       ]);

         // $category= Category::find($id);
        $category = Category::find($id);
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->save();


        session()->flash('success','data updated successfully');
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.categories.index');
}
```

Comment: Worked with me when changed to :    $category->name = $request->Name;   not name     // Thannks for help

Comment: @Qonvex620 he has an issue in his html name field :-/

Comment: Wat what's the issue ?